# Unable to access my spring boot API on another computer when its port is in use on that computer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api-design

I made an API on spring boot in one pc, and started it on localhost. I can access it on that pc and on any other pc using it's IP address.

However, I was got a time out error when attempting to access the API from a friend's laptop, and found out that he was running another spring boot api on the same port as the one my api was running on in my pc. After changing it, the api could be accessed.

I asked my project manager, and he says that this shouldn't happen, that there was no connection between the ports on my original pc and this one. However, this is practically not the case. Can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please clarify because your question contains the answer why you can't start a second application on the same port already.

Comment: My english isn't very good, maybe I wasn't clear. 

API A is running on PC X on port 1, 
PC Y is running API B on port 1, 
When I try accessing API A on PC Y, it gives me a gateway timeout. I wanted to know why.